# Drag and drop fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm developing an app that shows RTSP stream with multiple video sources in one screen. I'm using LibVLC framework, and to achieve multiple video surfaces in one screen i'm using fragments. These fragments are storing inside grid-like container like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_container_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_container_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/store_17" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_container_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_container_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need to change position of fragment with video using drag and drop. Any ideas how can i achieve that?